# FilteringSelect with a delimiter

Tags: dojo

The following code works fine,But only one value at a time,  i want more than one value to selected separated by a comma.
for Example i selected Alabama from the dropdown and then when i give comma Example:Alabama, and enter a new letter,say C [Example:Alabama,C],the next set of items  must be displayed in the dropdown
So finally i would be having the following values in the TextBox Example:Alabama,California

```
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, FilteringSelect){
    var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
            {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
            {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
            {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
            {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
            {name:"California", id:"CA"},
            {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
            {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
        ]
    });
    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
            id: "stateSelect",
            name: "state",
            value: "CA",
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect");
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input id="stateSelect">
<p>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value'))">Get value</button>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('displayedValue'))">Get displayed value</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dojo Filtering select widget does not allow multiple items to be selected.  Consider using a Dojo MultiSelect widget as an alternative.

See:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/MultiSelect.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look at CheckedMultiSelect:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect.html

It has both the dropdown and the multiseletion. To change the displayed label, the interesting code is in function `_updateSelection`:

```
        this.dropDownButton.set("label", this.multiple ?
            lang.replace(this._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText, {num: i}) :
            label);
```

It displays label `n item(s) selected`. If you want items separated with commas, it's the good place to plug in your code.

Comment: Does CheckedMultiSelect have a mechanism for filtering from a huge set of options like the autocomplete-style filtering select?